# SharePoint 2013 Migration - WideListSchema error is upgrade blocking

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I have a SharePoint 2007 site that has a list with a lot of fields,  We are trying to migrate this site to SharePoint 2013 (with a hop on SharePOint 2010).

The site gets upgraded onto SharePOint 2010 but when we upgrade it to SharePoint 2013,  we receive "WideListSchema" error,  this error is upgrade blocking so the site is not being upgraded.

---

Category        : WideListSchema
Error           : True
UpgradeBlocking : True
Message         : The list 'RMTAllExpertise' at URL '/SITES/xxx/Lists/xxx' has a schema that is incompatible with this version of 
                  SharePoint.
Remedy          : Delete some fields from the list 'xxx'."
Locations       :

---

I was wondering what are the new limitation on maximum number of fields of a SharePoint 2013 lists.  If it works in SharePOInt 2007/2010,  it should have worked in 2013.

Does any one knows about limitations in the numner of fields...

Regards,
Sudhir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is to remove columns (specially text column) in case you have more then 256 text columns.

Below are the text from TechNet articlehttp://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff382641.aspx.

“Delete excess columns from wide lists (lists with too many columns) or remove wide lists Wide lists are lists with more columns than fit in a single rowspan in the content database. During upgrade, the underlying storage in the database is changed to a sparse table structure, and a very wide list can cause upgrade to fail. Use the Test-SPContentDatabase command in Windows PowerShell to look for wide lists in the content databases and then remove excess columns, or remove the wide list before you upgrade.
For more information about maximum column sizes in a list, see Column limitshttp://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#Column.

- SharePoint 2013 can allow maximum of 8000 bytes for column information before it can reach the limit of 6 rows.  Please refer to Column Limitshttp://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#Column.

Also keep in mind that SharePoint does have some internal hidden field that is counted in this 8000 bytes limit,  so that leaves you about 7500 bytes of columns in your list.

Answer (score 0):

All the limits are here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx

Try increasing the MaxListItemRowStorage of the new WebApp.

Comment: I had a call with Microsoft, and the the person says that it might be one of the known issues with current release.  I will keep you all posted with my findnings...

Comment: did you the maxlistitemrowstorage change @SudhirKesharwani? I tried to change this in SharePoint 2013, and it is not working for me, so I may have to use your solution.

Comment: Mike, I remember this was an option,  however Microsoft support were not very optimistic on if this will solve this issue,  we figured out a lot of unwanted fields and removed them from the list.  Better to keep everything in the environment within hard limit.  Hope this helps